# Angular2- Radio button testing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I'm trying to test an HTML radio button with Karma-Jasmine in Angular 2.
My HTML code is like this

```
<label class="color-dark display-block" *ngFor="let userGroup of userGroups">
    <input type="radio" id="stateRadio" name="statusRadio(click)="selectedGroup(seGrp = statusLabel.value)" [checked]="statusLabel.value === selectionStatus">{{statusLabel.value}}
</label>
```

Spec

```
it('should have defined number of userGroup radio buttons', () => {
    el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#stateRadio')).nativeElement
    expect(el.click()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I'm getting error - TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'fixture.debugElement.query(platform_browser_1.By.css('#stateRadio')).nativeElement')

In the spec el type is HTMLElement and I'm id to By.css() as the css class-color-dark display-block is common to other input types too. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: HTML element id's are supposed to be unique, FYI.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes. But my approach is not working

Comment: I was suggesting that `id="stateRadio"` it's not a reliable selector because it's created in an `*ngFor`.

Comment: What's the alternative?

Comment: There are many alternatives, and keep in mind this may not be the cause of your issue, but you should still fix it. Basically you can either generate IDs, or use another kind of selector such as element.class. generating IDs could be problematic as the tests might we'll get out of sync with the code.

Comment: I'm also not sure that I see the value of this test. If your user interface is changed to use a drop down list instead I fail to see why that should fail a test

Comment: Agree you need unique ids. You might also check whether userGroups has length > 0 in your test case. An uninitialized userGroups could cause no element to be found.

Answer (score 1):

id attributes do need to be unique.  To make the id's in the for loop unique:

Change:

```
*ngFor="let userGroup of userGroups"
```

to:

```
*ngFor="let userGroup of userGroups; let i = index;"
```

And also change:

```
id="stateRadio"
```

to something like this:

```
id="stateRadio[{{i}}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the component's logic, I would have to guess that the userGroups array is empty or undefined, so nothing is being rendered, thus:

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#stateRadio'))
```

returns null.